# Solving 1D Poisson Equation with Gauss Seidel Red Black

Tags: c++, linear-equation

I'm trying to solve a 1D poisson equation to model potential at 10 micrometer intervals in the dielectric of a capacitor. The main issue I'm having is the red/black Gauss-Seidel code appears to not actually update the values in the potential matrix and therefore does not converge.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float x=0;
    bool exit = false;
    float V [11] = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
    float Q [11];
    // set up q matrix
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        Q[i] = 50*sin(3.14*x/0.00001);
        x += 0.00001;
    }
    while(!exit)
    {
        if(V[10] <= 3.29)
        {
            // red sweep
            for(int i=1; i <= 10; i+=2)
            {
                V[i] = -0.5*(0.00001*Q[i]-V[i-1]-V[i+1]);
            }
            //black sweep
            for(int j=2; j <= 10; j+=2)
            {
                V[j] = -0.5*(0.00001*Q[j]-V[j-1]-V[j+1]);
            }
        }
        else exit=true;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
        cout << V[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch out, I believe you are reading past the bounds of your `V` array during the black sweep:

```
//black sweep
for(int j=2; j <= 10; j+=2)
{
    V[j] = -0.5*(0.00001*Q[j]-V[j-1]-V[j+1]);
}
```

When `j=10`, you will be accessing `V[11]`, which is beyond the length of your V array. That will be reading in uninitialized memory, so that probably explains why your equation isn't converging.

Comment: Actually, I believe you would be reading into the Q array, not uninitialized memory. Either way, it's probably not the behavior you want.